# Force to www not working for subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

This is not working with subfolder.

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com/wordpress/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exemple.com/wordpress/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this is working.

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exemple.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemple\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*)$ http://www.exemple.com/wordpress/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```